# Inserting block in home page

Tags: layout, blocks

In my one-col phtml I echo this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('nav') ?>
```

and in my local layout xml, I have this.

```
<layout>
    <default>    
        <reference name="nav">
             <block type="core/text_list" name="nav" template="nav.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Am I missing a step? Why isn't this showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your layout is declared a bit wrong.  Firstly you are referencing a block with name `nav` but you are also trying to declare this block inside `nav` by referencing it.  Layout names must be unique over the whole page, so you are effectively trying to declare a block inside itself.

Also you have declared a block of type `core/text_list`. The job of this block is purely to render out child blocks added to it, so think of it as a container for other blocks rather than a block which will have it's own content render.  If you look at core layout files, you will never see a template defined for blocks of type `core/text_list`, you will just see these blocks referenced and child blocks added.

If you don't want to have child blocks of your block just change the type to either `core/template`, or `page/html` if it's the frontend, and add it to `root` as the parent (as you are calling `getChildHtml()` inside the root template):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <block type="page/html" name="nav" template="nav.phtml" parent="root" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

If you want to have child blocks automatically render out then you need to add children to the `core/text_list` block you declare.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="nav_parent">
                <block type="page/html" name="nav" template="nav.phtml" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

You would then use a call to `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('nav_parent') ?>` in your root template which would render out the child block `nav` (and any other child blocks of `nav_parent` you added).

Comment: I used the 1st example you provide and it works, thank you so much for such detail explanation. I think I understand much better about the relationship between layout and block. Thank you.

Comment: if I use the 1st example, I can't use `$this->`? can you briefly explain how `$this` came to be? and how to use it? I will open a question, and provide a link later. thanks for any help.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48906/how-this-works-in-magenta-and-how-to-use-it

Answer (score 1):

do you have somewhere the `<block name="nav">`?

Answer (score 1):

try this in your local.xml

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="nav" as="nav" template="page/navigation/nav.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

here you can find more details about block types used in layout :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633307/understanding-magento-block-and-block-type

hope that helps.