# how `$this` works in magento. and how to use it

Tags: layout, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <block type="page/html" name="nav" template="nav.phtml" parent="root" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

I have create a xml. such as this. but I can't use any of the `$this->` method in the `nav.phtml`. 
Can some one tell me why? and how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. Do you mean there are no IDE suggestions on $this-> methods?

Comment: no, `$this` object is empty inside my nav.phtml. I am wondering how to call it.

Answer (score 3):

`$this` in `nav.phtml` can only call functions from the block "page/html" which is `Mage_Page_Block_Html` and it's parents.  You can turn on the Template Path Hints and Add Block Names to Hints from System->Configuration.  Set Current Configuration Scope to your Store, then select Developer->Debug.

Comment: so the problem, is the type of block I am using? I am trying to do something simple as output `$this->getSkinUrl('images/example.jpg')`

Comment: it will only point to the base skin, instead of the custom skin I declare.

Comment: Did you configure your custom skin theme correctly in the Config settings?
`System->Configuration`, set Current Configuration Scope, `General->Design` Set the Correct Package and Theme Name for your custom skin.

Comment: yes I did, I am sure. since everything else is grab from the skin folder.

Comment: To debug this problem, just do a simple
`<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/example.jpg') ?>` and see where it's trying to get the URL from.
[Magento's Theme Hierarchy](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy) can help you understand how the Magento Theme works.